# Getting non null latest value in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I want to get the latest non null value across all the variables. For example, in this data set, we have 3 service dates.

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame( {'PatientID': [1, 1, 1], 
'Date': ['01/01/2018', '01/15/2018','01/20/2018'],
'Height': ['Null', '178', 'Null'],
'Weight': ['Null', '182', '190'],
'O2 Level': ['95', '99', '92'],
'BPS': ['120', 'Null', 'Null'],
'DPS': ['80', 'Null', 'Null']})
```

[Example Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuctA.png)
[image]

As an output I need something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'PatientID': [1], 
'Height': ['178'],
'Weight': ['190'],
'O2 Level': ['92'],
'BPS': ['120'],
'DPS': ['80']})
```

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMZRL.png)

[image]

My original data set has thousands of patients and 100+ covariates. Currently I am using a triple loop to achieve this task, which is very inefficient. I am looking for more efficient solutions.

Comment: Are dates always sorted?

Comment: Sorting is easy so lets assume that data set is sorted by patient id and dates in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first remove column `Date`, replace `null` to `NaN`s and then call [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
d = {'PatientID': [1, 1, 1], 
'Date': ['01/01/2018', '01/15/2018','01/20/2018'],
'Height': ['Null', '178', 'Null'],
'Weight': ['Null', '182', '190'],
'O2 Level': ['95', '99', '92'],
'BPS': ['120', 'Null', 'Null'],
'DPS': ['80', 'Null', 'Null']}
c = ['PatientID','Date','Height','Weight','O2 Level','BPS','DPS']
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=c)
print (df)
   PatientID        Date Height Weight O2 Level   BPS   DPS
0          1  01/01/2018   Null   Null       95   120    80
1          1  01/15/2018    178    182       99  Null  Null
2          1  01/20/2018   Null    190       92  Null  Null
```

---

```
print (df.drop('Date', 1).replace('Null', np.nan))
   PatientID Height Weight O2 Level  BPS  DPS
0          1    NaN    NaN       95  120   80
1          1    178    182       99  NaN  NaN
2          1    NaN    190       92  NaN  NaN

df = df.drop('Date', 1).replace('Null', np.nan).groupby('PatientID', as_index=False).last()
print (df)
   PatientID Height Weight O2 Level  BPS DPS
0          1    178    190       92  120  80
```

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for "non null" values. I think last() function would just provide me the latest row by date.

Comment: It working, because there is replace `Null` to `NaN`s.

Comment: It is giving me values for Weight and O2 level only. Other covariates are null

Comment: What are `null` values? Maybe need change `.replace('Null', np.nan)` to `.replace('null', np.nan)`

Comment: Because `print (df.drop('Date', 1).replace('Null', np.nan))` does not replace, because no `Null` values or some another reason.

Comment: By null I meant `NaN` s. I replaced null with `NaN` but I only get values for Weight and O2 Level. Other variables are 'NaN's

Comment: If run my solution with my answer you get different output as me?

Comment: I had some of my variables as `dtype(objects)`. I converted those to floats and now your solution is working like a charm. You are awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

You can using `groupby` + `last`

```
df.groupby(['Patient ID']).last()
```